# Smooth Hover Transition

Tags: wordpress, css, css-transitions

When hovering over a featured post I have the find out more box appear and the box with the title and text moves up slightly over the image. Now I just want it to have a slow transition rather than appear suddenly. Any Ideas? Thanks

```css
.homepage-news {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-info {
 padding: 16px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c80909;
}

.content-info h3 {
 font-family: 'Rasa', serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #161616;
 margin: 0;
}

.content-info p {
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1rem;
 color: #161616;
 margin: 6px 0;
}

.homepage_news {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #161616;
 width: 31.3%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin: 1%;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.homepage_news:hover .content-info{
 position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.homepage_news:hover .find-out-more-btn {
 display: block;
 margin-top: -14px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #c80909;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}

 .find-out-more-btn {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage_news">
           <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($latest_news); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($latest_news); ?>"
               alt="<?php echo $latest_news->post_title; ?>">
            <div class="content-info">
             <h3><?php echo $latest_news->post_title; ?></h3>
             <p><?php echo $latest_news->post_content; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="find-out-more-btn">Find Out More</div>
           </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Use transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your stylesheet will probably get you most of the way there:

```
.content-info, .find-out-more-btn{
  transition: 0.4s all;
}
```

You can adjust the `0.4s` timing of the transition to whatever number you'd like.

If you need to support IE8 / 9, these won't work, but it degrades nicely.